# Track field completion on Standard Objects

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, visualforce-component

I want to be able to track ***record level % completion*** in terms of fields populated.

> For e.g on one Account record , I have 50 fields that needs to be
>   populated and the user has only entered for 25 fields. So, the %
>   completion is 50% which **I need to show in bar format (progress bar)**.

Any thoughts on how I can achieve this on every record for all standard objects??

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need this on every record? or do you want just an average number on all of the records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a display-only visual, such as in Visualforce, you can use the following logic:

Controller:

```
public with sharing class recordProgress {
    public Integer progress { get; set; }
    public Integer completed { get; set; }
    public Integer total { get; set; }
    Id recordId;

    public void setComponentRecordId(Id recordId) {
        if(progress == null) {
            progress = 0;
            this.recordId = recordId;
            try {
                Map<String, SObjectField> fieldMap = recordId.getSObjectType().getDescribe().fields.getMap();

                String[] fields = new String[0];

                for(String field: fieldMap.keyset()) {
                    DescribeFieldResult result = fieldMap.get(field).getDescribe();
                    if(result.isAccessible() && result.isUpdateable()) {
                        fields.add(field);
                    }
                }

                SObject record = Database.query(
                    'select '+
                    string.join(fields,',')+
                    ' from '+
                    string.valueof(recordid.getsobjecttype())+
                    ' where id = \''+
                    recordId+
                    '\'');
                for(String field: fields) {
                    progress += record.get(field) != null ? 1 : 0;
                }
                total = fields.size();
                completed = progress;
                progress /= fields.size()/100;
            } catch(exception e) {

            }
        }
    }
    public Id getComponentRecordId() {
        return recordId;
    }
    public Integer getRemainingProgress() {
        return 100-progress;
    }
}
```

Component:

```
<apex:component controller="recordProgress" selfClosing="true">
    <apex:attribute assignTo="{!componentRecordId}" description="Record to check" name="recordId" required="true" type="Id"/>
    <progress value="{!progress}" max="100"/> {!completed}/{!total}
</apex:component>
```

Example usage:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <c:recordProgress recordId="{!Account.Id}"/>
</apex:page>
```

You'll need one page per object type, as described here. You might want to adjust the if/then statement to determine special rules, such as if the field is a lookup, etc. I wrote this to be as generic as possible.

You could also add a custom field on each object, and convert this code to a trigger, storing the progress as a field value. This would allow reporting on the progress of fields, including average, etc.